# JQuery's .on('change') and an HTML5 input[type=color]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing the website for my school's  [Virtual Enterprises](https://veinternational.org/about/)  class and need some help.

First off my code:

```
$(document).on('click', "#your-nook-theme-btn", function() {
var your_nook = $(this).parent(".og-grid").attr("#your-nook-theme-btn");
    $(".og-grid").hide('slide', 'swing', '5000ms', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
    $(".main").prepend('<br> <div id="YN">Welcome to Your Nook, Modern Nook Design\'s newest innovation in interior design. Please pick your room\'s color scheme below. <br> <br> <div class="container" class="YN-order_form"><form method="POST" class="YN-order_form" id="YN-order_form"><span id="main-color-span">  <label for="main-color">Main Color: </label> <input type="color" id="main-color" value="#000000"></span><span id="accent-color-span"> <label for="accent-color">Accent Color: </label><input type="color" id="accent-color" name="accent-color" value="#ff0000"></span> <br> <br> <span id="step2"> Good. Now let\'s pick your decor. </span> <br> <br> </form></div></div>');
});

$(document).on('change', "#accent-color", function() {
    var accent = $(this).parent("YN").attr("#accent-color");
    $("#step2").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

[image: Image of website]

So I want a span, `#step2`, that is just below the two `<input type="color">` fields to fade in when the user clicks on the red input field; however, I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I've tried `.click` and `.change`, but haven't had any luck. Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated. Both the inputs and the span are added dynamically.

Comment: can u put ur html and js code in this link:  http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @user00000341 http://jsfiddle.net/ktzkyyqg/ Click on the picture with the description `Your Nook`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your css for step2 and your code will work:-

```
#step2 {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm still sorta new to design so people like you and everyone else who helped me are the best.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize this with CSS and Javascript.

keep the initial style of the `span` to be `visibility:hidden`. Upon click, change the `visibility` attribute to `visible`.

The jQuery function is `$("#<id>").attr("visibility", "visible");`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The span still stays hidden. My code isn't throwing any JS errors in the console so I think I might just have the wrong method.

Comment: This is instead of FadeIn function. if you want to still use FadeIn, then you need to set the style as display:none.